# Sort Diagonally Two Dimensional Array

Tags: c++

Firstly I created my two dimensional array, then I translated it to one dimensional array and I bubble sorted the 1D array, but after I didn't find the pattern to bring it back to 2D array diagonally sorted.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>

const int r = 10;
const int c = 10;
const int lim = r * c;
int A[r][c] = { 0 };
int B[lim];

using namespace std;

void generatearray(int A[][], int r, int c){
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i = 0; i < r; i++)
{
for (int j = 0; j < c; j++)
{
A[i][j] = rand() % lim;
}
}
}

void transformingto1Darray(int A[r][c], int b[lim]){
int p = 0;

for (int m = 0; m < r; m++){
for (int n = 0; n < c; n++){

B[p] = A[m][n];
p++;

}
}
}

void sorting1Darray(int B[][]){
int temp = 0;

for (int k = 0; k < lim - 1; k++){
for (int i = 0; i < lim - 1; i++)
if (B[i] > B[i + 1]){
temp = B[i];
B[i] = B[i + 1];
B[i + 1] = temp;
}
}
}

void sortingdiagonally2Darray(int A[][], int B[]){



int main{
generatearray(A);
transformingto1Darray(A, B);
sorting1Darray(B);
sortingdiagonally2Darray(A, B);

return 0;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a wonky solution but it dose work. Because of the way multidimensional indexing works the value in `B[i]` will be equal to the value in `A[0][i]`.

In your case you want something like this in your `sortingdiagonally2Darray` function.

```
for (int i = 0; i > r * c; i++) {
     A[0][i] = B[i];
}
```

This works because under the hood arrays are just pointers. `B[x]` is syntactic sugar for `*(B + x)` and `A[0][x]` will equate to `*(*(A + 0) + x)` because it's a pointer to a pointer (hence the double star/double brackets).